# Put a span inside <a> of Nav::widget in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, nav

I am trying to create a menu in `Yii2` using `Nav::widget` and what I have to do is to render the menu like this:

```
<li id="dashboard">
            <a href="<?php echo Yii::$app->homeUrl; ?>?r=users/dashboard" class="active-title">
                <span class="nav-icon"><i class="icon-dashboard icon-2x"></i></span>
                <span class="sidebar-menu-item-text">Dashboard</span></a>            
        </li>
```

And what I am currently doing is this:

```
[
    'label' => 'Dashboard',
    'url' => ['users/dashboard'],
    'options' => ['id' => 'dashboard'],
],
```

And this renders in browser like this:

```
<li id="dashboard" class="active"><a href="/yiitwo/laps/frontend/web/index.php?r=users%2Fdashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
```

So, what I want to do is to put a `span` inside `<a>` tag. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[
    'label' => '<span class="nav-icon"><i class="icon-dashboard icon-2x"></i></span><span class="sidebar-menu-item-text">Dashboard</span>',
    'encode' => false,
    'url' => ['users/dashboard'],
    'options' => ['id' => 'dashboard'],
],
```